# Select a specific anchor jquery

Tags: jquery

i have 6 links on my page like

```
<a rel='popup'></a>
```

i am selecting the link as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var popUp = $("a[rel='popup']");
    popUp.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();         
        alert("pop clicked");  <-- apperaring 6 times
        var thiis = $(this);
        var href = thiis.attr("href");
        });
    });
```

the problem is alert pop clicked is appearing 6 times, can anybody help me figure out the problem. I want it to appear only once
Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work fine to me (only one alert per click) in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/qnr7M/

Comment: Is this your actual code, or have you reduced it? I don't see anything that would cause that behavior, unless your `<a>` tags are all nested.

Comment: You have six anchor tags and you're attaching the event handler to all of them. That's the way it should work. You don't mean that you click one anchor and the alert appears six times per the one click, do you? Because that would be odd.

Comment: @patrick dw -- yup i reduced the code the links are nested in table > td's...

Comment: @FishBasketGordo im clicking on one link and the alert is appearing 6 times...

Comment: @john: I meant nested inside each other. Apparently that's not the case. I posted an answer. Let me know if your situation is similar.

Comment: This code works fine. There should be some mix-up with the HTML. Can you show the whole HTML?

Comment: works for me too, you better take a shower john.

Comment: Works for me - see this http://jsfiddle.net/Urc5q/

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins -- thankyou all P.S i'll take a shower when i get home :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code is reduced, the only thing I can think of is that your actual code is calling the `alert()` (or whatever code is repeating) as a callback to the [`animate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method (or some other method that accepts a callback).

```
popUp.animate({/***/}, 1000, function() {

    alert("pop clicked"); // this will run 6 times

});
```

So if you're running some code off the cached set of `popUp` elements, and it takes a callback, the callback will run once for each element.

---

**EDIT:** Another posibility would be that you're caching the set, using the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method, but applying the handler to the entire set during every iteration. That would cause 6 handlers to be attached to each element instead of one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var popUp = $("a[rel='popup']");

    popUp.each(function() {

         // this would cause 6 handlers to be assigned to each element 
         //    instead of one
       popUp.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();         
            alert("pop clicked");  
            var thiis = $(this);
            var href = thiis.attr("href");
       });
    });
});
```

If this is the case, then instead of:

```
popUp.click(function(e){
```

you should do:

```
$(this).click(function(e){
```

Comment: nope they are not nested inside each other i tried `stopPropagation()` but to no effect

Comment: @john: Yes, but did you consider my answer? Are the alerts happening inside a callback.

Comment: @john: There's something in your code that isn't in the question that is causing it. You'll need to add more info to the question. I have one other idea. I'll update my answer.

Comment: if its ok can you have look at the code i have uploaded the txt file, im using smarty templates php http://www.megaupload.com/?d=0PJEE1ON

Comment: @john: I'll take a look, but see my updated answer in the meantime.

Comment: @john: You're going to have to narrow it down for me. Which script should I be looking at, and what do I need to do on the page to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @john can you upload the html/javascript your php spits out please?

Comment: @patrick dw -- the edit helped me to get to the answer ... god bless you and tnx a ton ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. I've taken your code, put it in a table and it is running fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/93Mat/

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's just a repeat of the comments above that say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
var popUp = $("a[rel='popup']");

$(popUp).each(function(n, item){
    $(this).click(function(e){

       // your stuff goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for replying but once you cache the object again wrapping it in `$` is not necessary :) it should be `popUp.each`